# What's this casting error has to do with _id? "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "123" at path "_id"'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

I am trying to populate an array based on finding criteria for the following model.

```
function initSchemaAndModel() {
    observationNameAndTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        observationName:String,
        observationPrefixNumber:String,
        observationNumbersList: [{type:String, unique:true}]
    });

    ObservationNameAndTypeObject = mongoose.model("observation_name_and_type_model", observationNameAndTypeSchema);
}
```

This is the code for Populate method.

```
ObservationNameAndType.getObservationNameAndTypeModel()
    .findOne({observationName: "OBSERVATION_NAME"})
    .populate("observationNumbersList")
    .exec(function (err, observationNameAndTypeMatchedObject) {

        if(err) {
            console.error("error in finding ", err);
            return;
        }
        observationNameAndTypeMatchedObject.observationNumbersList.push(object);
        observationNameAndTypeMatchedObject.save();
    });
```

I am getting this error for some reason. I don't understand what's causing it.

```
 { [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "123" at path "_id"]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "123" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: '123',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined }
```

This is the data I inserted in the collection.

```
{observationName: "OBSERVATION_NAME", observationPrefixNumber: "1", observationNumbersList : "123"};
```

This is how it looks like in the Collection:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "57f13dd8607efc603a13168f"} , "observationName" : "OBSERVATION_NAME" , "observationPrefixNumber" : "1" , "observationNumbersList" : [ "123"] , "__v" : 0}
```

Comment: Because the _id is an object, not the string "123".

Comment: I understand. I am not asking mongoose to populate _id. I am asking mongoose to find a document with the mentioned finding criteria and then populate the ObservationNumberList array.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to populate subdocument until you are referring another model

```
ObservationNameAndType.getObservationNameAndTypeModel()
    .findOne({observationName: "OBSERVATION_NAME"})
    .exec(function (err, observationNameAndTypeMatchedObject) {

        if(err) {
            console.error("error in finding ", err);
            return;
        }
        observationNameAndTypeMatchedObject.observationNumbersList.push(object);
        observationNameAndTypeMatchedObject.save();
    });
```

if you need only then you may directly push using `$push` as following

```
ObservationNameAndType.update({observationName: "OBSERVATION_NAME"}, {$push: {observationNumbersList: object}}, function (err, observationNameAndTypeMatchedObject) {
   if(err) {
      console.error("error in finding ", err);
      return;
   }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "You do not need to populate subdocument until you are referring another model"?

Answer (score 0):

Population work only if the field is refer any collection.In your query you populate "observationNumbersList" but in schema you store only string.
Your schema should be

```
  observationNameAndTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        observationName:String,
        observationPrefixNumber:String,
        observationNumbersList: [{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId}]
    });
```

And if you have no use of population then remove  `.populate("observationNumbersList")`
from your query.